# Reduce dlib landmarks file size

Tags: android, dlib

while using the new [Dlib library for Android](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android) I have noticed that to detect faces, you need to load a landmark points DAT file to your project. The main issue is that the "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" file size is 98MB. Which is extremely slow to load when opening the Android camera to detect faces.

I have already seen this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435653/detecting-face-landmarks-points-in-android) with a similar case, but I do not understand the answer at all.

Any way to reduce the file size? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shape predictor trained mode file size depends on the count of points model training parameters.  Existing model has the size of 98 MB and provide state-of-the-art accuracy of facial points detection.
So you have three main ways to solve the problem:

1. some compression/quantization... that will change existing model. I will not help here - there are some answers in the question you are referenced
2. use different model training params. Existing model is trained with the code provided in "train_shape_predictor_ex" example in dlib package, but the training params are little different. simple running this example as-is with the images from example folder will give you model with the size of 15 MB. Yes, this model will be less-accurate, but this is the price of its small size
3. use less landmarks. to make this - use same "train_shape_predictor_ex" example, but remove some landmarks from training/testing dataset